# How to call JS function in newTextBoxDiv.after().html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I `document.write("<option></option>")` 500 options for select in a function named `laborlist()`. When user click on select it just print out all those 500plus s on page nothing else. I don't know how to call **javascrip**t or **php** function in `newTextBoxDiv.after().html`

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<select  class="select2_single form-control" name="jobrequest' + counter + '"><option></option>' + laborlist() + '</select>');
```

Another question is which method is faster to make database table of 500 laborlist and call it through **AJAX** or method i am using? Thank you

```
function laborlist(){
    var labourList = document.getElementById("labourList");
    // use innerHTML instead of document.write()
    labourList.innerHTML +="<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>and so on";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be possible.

Instead you can have a `id` for the `select` tag and use that `id` in `laborlist()` funtion to append `option` to it.

So it would be something like this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<select id="labourList" class="select2_single form-control" name="jobrequest' + counter + '"><option></option>' + '</select>');

function laborlist(){
    var labourList = document.getElementById("laborList");
    // use innerHTML instead of document.write()
    labourList.innerHTML += "<option>...</option>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work for me? no options are there, emty :(

Comment: What is your `laborlist()` function code? Add it to the question as well.

Comment: please check now.

Comment: Thank you but still not working in newTextBoxDiv.after().html(). Works in HTML but in second select which is in newTextBoxDiv.after().html, it does not work.